# "They are" or "that they are"?

Tags: that, omissibility

> It's clear they are honest.

vs.

> It's clear *that* they are honest.

Is there a difference? Is one more correct than the other?

Comment: I think (that) both are similar. These days, 'that' is dropped.

Comment: @RamPillai It's not just that they are similar, the shorter version _is_ the longer version with 'that' dropped. Although there is no apostrophe because an entire word has been omitted it is analagous to "it is" and "it's" in that there is no difference in meaning at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is a different case of omissibility of "that" after an adjective, not after a verb. So the question is NOT a duplicate of that.

Comment: @fev: They're all essentially the same *optional* use of the word "that", so I don't see it makes much difference whether it follows an adjective or a verb. But the first example in ***my*** duplink is *it should be **clear that** Hume argues [that reason has no role in moral determinations].* (So ***that*** should assuage your misgivings! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, your duplink is closer, although there is no accepted answer and the existing answers do not deal with this particular instance itself. I don't think this question should be closed. They are not perfect duplicates, I could not post my answer to this question as an answer to the duplicate you indicate...

Answer (score 3):

In your sentence

> It's *clear* ***that*** they are honest.

*that* is used as a conjunction to introduce the clause that serves as [the complement of the predicative adjective](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adjective-Complements.htm#:%7E:text=An%20adjective%20complement%20(also%20called,the%20subject%20of%20the%20clause).) ***clear***.

This is one instance when ***that*** can be omitted [there are other cases of omissibility of *that* but I will only deal with the particular case about which you are asking]:

> ***Adjective + that-clause***
> We use *be + adjective + that-clause* to express opinions and feelings. Some adjectives commonly used in this way are ***sure, certain, right, important, afraid, pleased, sorry, surprised, worried** [and we can add **clear** in this category]*. We can omit that *with no change in meaning*:
>
> - It’s *important **(that)*** we look at the problem in more detail. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses))

The omission of ***that*** is still controversial nowadays, especially in writing. Many advocate that omitting ***that*** is informal, but we are seeing a shift in use even in formal speech or written texts. [This site](http://www.english-for-students.com/Omitting-That.html) recommends:

> As a general rule, if the sentence feels just as good without the ***that***, if no ambiguity results from its omission, if the sentence is more efficient or elegant without it, then we can safely omit the ***that***.

In your case ***both versions of the sentence are correct***, but since there is no ambiguity and the sentence definitely feels less heavy without ***that***, I would use

> It's clear they are honest.

without any worry that the meaning is changed.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually extremely clear and helpful. I'm a bit amazed (that) someone would actually have documented such a small point of language so well!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference, and that is only one of formality. Whereas the conjunction is kept in formal writing, in everyday speech it is most times dropped. The meaning remains the same.  The relative pronoun "that" is also dropped similarly.
Nevertheless, "that" can't be dropped in all cases.

> PEU No **560** **that**: omission
> We can often leave out the conjunction *that*, especially in an informal style.
>
> **1** **indirect speech**
> *That* can be left out informally after many common reporting verbs.
>      ♦ *James **said (that)** he was feeling better.*
>      ♦ *I **thought (that)** you were in Ireland.*
> *That* cannot be dropped after certain verbs (e.g. *reply*, *telegraph*, *shout*) and  is not usually dropped after nouns.
>      ♦*James **replied that** he was feeling better.*
>      ♦*James **replied that** he was feeling better.*
>      ♦<s>*James replied  he was feeling better.*</s>
>      ♦*James **replied that** he was feeling better.*
>      ♦ *He disagreed with Copernicus' **view that** the earth went round the sun.*
>      (NOT … <s>Copernicus' view the earth went</s> …)
>
> **2 after adjectives**
> We can use *that*-clauses after some adjectives. *That* can be left out in more common expressions.
>      ♦ *I'm **glad (that)** you are all right.*
>      ♦ *It's **funny (that)** he hasn't written.*
>
> **3 conjunctions**
> *That* can be left out in an informal style in more common two-word conjunctions, such as *so that*, *such … that*, *now that*, *providing that*, *provided that*, *supposing that*, *considering that*, *assuming that*.
>      ♦ *Come in quietly **so (that)** she doesn't hear you.*
>      ♦ *I was having **such** a nice time **(that)** I didn't want to leave.*
>
> **4** **relative structures**
> We can usually leave the relative pronoun *that* when it is the object in a relative clause.
>      ♦ *Look! There are people **(that)** we met in Brighton.*

Comment: Also very helpful. One question, all these say when it can be left out. When is it obligatory to leave it in? What distinguishes the Copernicus sentence you quoted, in language terms? (Also if it's mandatory at times then logically in your 1st sentence, its not "only" one of formality, surely?)

Comment: @Stilez According to what I have read and heard, in rather formal writing, it is well not to omit "that", whether conjunction or pronoun. // What distinguishes it in my opinion is that you are likely to end up with clusters of nouns that are more or less awkward (in an other vein, consider "The rat the cat the dog chased killed ate the malt"). Let's say more precisely that _when it is dropped_ there is no other difference than in the degree of formality.

Comment: It's not *mandatory* to retain "that" after verbs such as ***reply, telegraph, shout***. It's purely a *stylistic choice* - as with @LPH's  *The rat the cat the dog chased killed ate the malt* example, which is syntactically "valid" despite being stylistically appalling. For example, I have no problem with the several different written instances of [***you replied you didn't know***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+you+replied+you+didn%27t%22) in Google Books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are, obviously, different schools of thought regarding this question also. See this for instance: https://rebecaschiller.com/grammar/keep-that-or-drop-that/

Comment: @LPH: Indeed. And ***that should cover that*** (as rebecaschiller elegantly summarizes in your link! :)